# How to write a date validator with grails command object?

Tags: validation, grails, command

I want to add a date expression validator in my command object, but I'm not sure what's the correct syntax...

```
class UserController {
    …
}
class DateServiceCommand {
    String date    //valid format is DD-MMM-YYYY, 01-APR-2011
    static constraints = {
        date(blank:false, ??? )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I encourage  you to accept the answer below, it's helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom [validator](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html):

```
import java.text.*

class DateServiceCommand {
    String date
    static constraints = {
        date blank: false, validator: { v ->
            def df = new SimpleDateFormat('dd-MMM-yyyy')
            df.lenient = false

            // parse will return null if date was unparseable
            return df.parse(v, new ParsePosition(0)) ? true : false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting...a question, in df.parse(v, new ParsePosition())....why did you not pass 'date' instead of v as the argument? I guess I'm not sure what v -> is doing

Comment: The `validator` closure's first argument is the value being validated, which in this case is the date. Using the actual `date` property within the `validator` closure won't work.

Comment: I'm still new to Groovy and its closure syntax, but this vaidator you provided does not compile; complains about the last ')' just before the ?, and I can't seem to fix it

Comment: Apologies, there was an extra parenthesis there. I've removed it.

Comment: Why is `new ParsePosition(0)` necessary here?